# Callback after store updation on child component?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

In my App, store gets updated whenever an event is dispatched. But the problem is I have a child component.

**Store:**

```
state.name = 'Jack'; //initial state value
```

**Child Component:**

```
this.props.updateName('Micheal'); 
this.printName();

printName() {   
  console.log(this.props.name); // 'Jack' 
}
```

After a while I call the same function.

```
this.printName(); // 'Micheal'
```

My question is that, is there any way to callback a function in child component when store is updated?

Answer (score 0):

The child component gets the new state via props. So, the componentWillReceiveProps will do the trick.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.name !== this.props.name) {
    console.log(this.props.name, nextProps.name);
  }
}
```